# Question about: How to show backup ads now that AdSense doesn't have the ability to do so for you?

Tags: html

I have some questions!

I use Adsense code on my site.

My question is, how to ad backup affiliate code in to the code below?

Also how do I add the affiliate code in 2 diferent sizes (I want to add the 728x90 banner on the desktop to appear and 300x250 banner on mobile phone to appear) when Adsense is not loading any ads on desktop and mobile.

THIS IS THE BACKUP CODE I HAVE:

// Run when the DOM content is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
// AdSense ads lazy load, so they can't be examined right away
setTimeout(function(){
// Search the DOM for ad slots assuming they all have  around them
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("adsenseads")
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
// See if adsense loaded an ad by checking for an iframe
if(x[i].innerHTML.search(/iframe/i)==-1){
// No ad loaded
x[i].innerHTML="BACKUP AD CONTENT HERE";
}
}
},3000); // 3000ms or 3 seconds
});

AFFILIATE CODE 300X250 :

[http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online"](http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online%22) rel="nofollow">

a target="_blank" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#028ACC; text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online" rel="nofollow">

AFFILIATE CODE 728X90 :

[http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online"](http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online%22) rel="nofollow">

a target="_blank" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#028ACC; text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.cursos24horas.com.br/parceiro.asp?cod=promocao124728&url=cursos/curso-de-ingles-online" rel="nofollow">

I hope that someone can help me please!

Thank you !!

Daniël

Comment: The most refined solution would be via ad manager. Have you explored Google ad manager (formerly DFP)?